# How create unique slug for two tables

Tags: php, cakephp

I have field slug in posts, and field slug in categories. At this moment I can create unique slugs inside the model, PostModel or CategoryModel. I must validate that this slug be unique in both tables. How can I do this?

This is what I have for validate unique slug

```
public function slug(Entity $entity)
{
if ($entity-\>get('slug') != '') {
return $entity-\>get('slug');
}

        $value = $entity->get($this->getConfig('field'));
    
        $extension = '';
        if ($entity->type == 'attachment') {
            $name =  implode('.', explode('.', $value, -1));
            $extension = str_replace($name, "", $value);
            $value = $name;
        }
        $clean_value = Text::transliterate($value, 'Latin-ASCII;');
    
        $string = Text::slug(strtolower($clean_value), $this->getConfig('replacement'));
    
        $slug = $this->uniqueSlug($entity, $string, $this->getConfig('replacement'), $extension);
    
        $entity->set($this->getConfig('slug'), $slug);
    }
    
    public function uniqueSlug(Entity $entity, $slug, $separator, $extension)
    {
        debug($this->_table);
        $primaryKey = $this->_table->getPrimaryKey();
        $field = $this->_table->aliasField($this->getConfig('slug'));
    
        $conditions = $this->conditions($entity, $slug . $extension);
    
        $i = 0;
        $suffix = '';
    
        while ($this->_table->exists($conditions)) {
            $i++;
            $suffix = $separator . $i;
            $conditions[$field] = $slug . $suffix . $extension;
        }
    
        return $slug . $suffix . $extension;
    }
 protected function conditions($entity, $slug)
    {
        $primaryKey = $this->_table->getPrimaryKey();
        $field = $this->_table->aliasField($this->getConfig('slug'));
    
        $conditions = [$field => $slug];
    
        if ($id = $entity->{$primaryKey}) {
            $conditions['NOT'][$this->_table->aliasField($primaryKey)] = $id;
        }
        dd($conditions);
        return $conditions;
    }
    
    public function uniqueTogether()
    {
        Post and Categories
    }
```

Comment: Assuming we're talking unique URL slugs here, why not create a `slug` table and link posts, pages, categories, pictures, albums... whatever you like basically, to that table?

Answer (score 0):

Use column indexes as unique, and check insert/update statements success or fails after posts. If you want to use case sensitive values you can try binary data fields too.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-varbinary.html